# What do "moderator tools" consist of?

Tags: discussion

Once a CV participant has a reputation of 10,000, a threshold is reached which grants them access to *moderator tools*.

Would someone describe what these tools enable that participant to do? Edit other participants' comments? Delete other participants' comments?

Elaboration would be useful.

Answer (score 10):

They're as described in the help page:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Only diamond moderators can edit/delete other users' comments.

There's also a site-wide elaboration of the role of moderators here: [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't edit or delete other users' comments; only ♦ moderators are capable of that. For some more explanation, see the [FAQ about comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/295232).

The [Help Center](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) pretty much sums up what you *do* get; personally, I find the 'edit tags inline' feature the most helpful and the ability to view deleted posts the most interesting. (I don't have 10k here but I do on a few other sites in the network.)

There's also an FAQ page on Meta Stack Exchange: [What are the moderation tools available to 10,000+ reputation users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4565/295232)